# SSAS DatabaseCollection doesn't contain Cubes

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssas

I was trying to retrieve a list of SSAS [Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.database.aspx) and their [Cubes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.cube.aspx) from an SSAS [Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.server.aspx) and I found this piece of code somewhere online (code is VB.NET, but issue is the same in C#):

```
Private Function GetCubesBad() As DatabaseCollection
    Dim databaseCollection As DatabaseCollection

    Using server As New Server
        server.Connect(String.Format("Data Source={0};Connect Timeout=30", "MYSERVER"))

        databaseCollection = server.Databases

        server.Disconnect()
    End Using

    Return databaseCollection
End Function
```

But this only returns a list Databases, not containing any Cubes.

Then I fiddled around with it a bit, and eventually got it to work like this:

```
Private Function GetCubesGood() As List(Of Cube)
    Dim cubeCollection As New List(Of Cube)

    Using server As New Server
        server.Connect(String.Format("Data Source={0};Connect Timeout=30", "MYSERVER"))

        For Each database As Database In server.Databases
            For Each cube As Cube In database.Cubes
                cubeCollection.Add(cube)
            Next
        Next

        server.Disconnect()
    End Using

    Return cubeCollection
End Function
```

Now I'm curious as to why the first function doesn't work...

EDIT:

When I modify the `GetCubesBad` function like this:

```
databaseCollection = server.Databases

For Each database As Database In databaseCollection
    Dim dummy = database.Cubes
Next
```

it works like a charm. So it seems necessary to call the Cubes property once for every Database while connected to the Server, else the Cubes property remains empty.

Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: How are you testing to determine that the cubes property is empty?   What are you trying to do with the returned databaseCollection?

Comment: I was trying to use the returned DatabaseCollection to show its Cubes and their last processed time in a ListView.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to try to do this?

Comment: I'm using a nested For Each loop: `For Each database As Database In GetCubesBad()` and `For Each cube As Cube In database.Cubes`. Then I add `cube.Name` to a ListView. But the Cubes property is always empty.

Comment: Why do you want to disconnect immediately and cannot stay connected until you have fetched everything you need?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, as a workaround. I add every Cube to a List before the connection closes. I'm just curious about the behaviour. Why aren't they accessible from the returned DatabaseCollection after the connection is closed?